# How to write function considering possible aliasing

Tags: c++, c

I'd like to write a function with a prototype like the following

```
void fun(Thing *one, Thing *two, Thing *ret);
```

I'd like to consider the fact that `ret` may or may not be aliased by `one` or `two`. This should be determined at runtime if needed, and the appropriate code called.

Is this a bad idea? Are there language semantics to have this?

EDIT: I haven't made clear that I don't want to test by hand like `if (one == ret || two == ret)` which naturally works but seems very verbose to me. Also, I don't want duplicated code for two almost identical cases (only the qualifier differs). I am more looking for what is idiomatically a good solution, and if there are any language semantics supporting such cases.

Comment: Easy... `if (ret == one || ret == two) { /*aliased*/ } else { /* not aliased */ }`

Comment: @Caribou think of a case when the call to the function is `fun(&a,&b,&a);`

Comment: @RoeeGavirel yep - I commented to quick ;)

Comment: just return by value and be done with it

Comment: @Alf A good solution if `Thing` is copyable.  But what if it isn't?  Or if only one or two attributes of `ret` should be modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot depends on the semantics of the classes in question, but it's extremely rare to need a test for aliasing.  Just obtain all of the information you need from `one` and `two` before you start modifying anything.  You might also want to ensure that you've finished anything which might raise an exception before starting modifications as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible and a lot of time used for example in "Swap" functions. you can check it with the values of the pointers:

```
void fun(Thing *one, Thing *two, Thing *ret)
{
    if (ret == one || ret == two)
    {
        //Alias - Spacial case
        return;
    }
    //Not Alias, continue usually...
}
```

EDIT: after reading your edit, it seems you asking if there is a way to know if a function received the same value in two different parameters without using "if" statement.
Then no, it's not possible to achieve this in C nor C++.
Because after all, pointer or not, it's just a parameter with a value...

Comment: But why?  Usually, if you start having to worry about aliasing of objects, you're doing something wrong.  (C style arrays are a different matter.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't know what is the implementation you are wishing to achieve. And maybe pointers can be avoided here. But if you want to do it, this is how.

Comment: same as checking that none of the input values is null. unless you are working in the "garbage in garbage out" way, but this is also imply for the aliasing problem.

Comment: Well, if he doesn't like `if`, then there's always `?:`:-).